# How to capture checkbox value on submit in the form of array of object in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some checkbox in the structure of parent child,I need to capture/console the value of checkbox based on selection in the output format( already given in the code as output as a hardcoded format). Here is the code below

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child11<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
                <li>child12<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent2</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child2<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent3</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child3<span class="pull-right"> <input type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div><button type="submit">submit</button></div>
    <p>output - [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]}]</p>
</div>
```

### script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('output - [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]}]');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html needs little bit of tweaking. I added data-child attribute to input to make retrieving name easier.

Here is an example with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("button").on("click", function() {
    let output = [];
    jQuery("#leftNavBar > ul").each(function() {
      _this = jQuery(this);
      const name = _this.find('.parentNav').text();
      const checkbox = _this.find("input[type='checkbox']");

      const isChecked = checkbox.filter(function() {
        return jQuery(this).is(":checked");
      });

      if (isChecked.length > 0) {
        let values = [];
        isChecked.map(function(ind, ele) {
          values.push(jQuery(this).attr("data-child"));
        });

        let obj = {
          name: name,
          values: values
        }
        output.push(obj);
      }
    });

    console.log(output);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child11 <span class="pull-right"><input checked type="checkbox" data-child='child1'></span></li>
        <li>child12 <span class="pull-right"><input checked type="checkbox" data-child='child2'></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent2</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child2 <span class="pull-right"><input checked type="checkbox" data-child='child2'></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent3</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child3 <span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" data-child='child3'></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
  <p>output - [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]}]</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to work without adding data-child ,I am not able to fetch it dynamically in my project,its giving error

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by dynamically. You can wrap the words child1, child2 .. etc in a span with a class and query that class name.

Comment: Its resolved by adding value instead of data-child in my html